# SQL Alchemy scoped session changes are not visible to other scopes

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have the following test, db.session and db.read_replica_session both talking to the same database in test, when I commit in the first one, the second one is not able to see the changes, whats the reason?

The sessions are both two separate SQLAlchemy Scoped Sessions that use the same connection string underneath.

```
card = db.session.query(Card).first()
card.display_name = "RANDOM"
db.session.add(card)
db.session.commit()

card_from_rr = (
    db.read_replica_session.query(Card).filter(Card.id == card.id).one()
)
assert card_from_rr.display_name == card.display_name
assert card_from_rr.id == card.id
```

> ```
>   assert card_from_rr.display_name == card.display_name
> ```

E       AssertionError: assert equals failed

db.read_replica_session connection info:

<connection object at 0x11bba23b0; dsn: 'user=postgres password=xxx dbname=test host=localhost port=5444', closed: 0>

db.session connection info:

<connection object at 0x10eba5000; dsn: 'user=postgres password=xxx dbname=test host=localhost port=5444', closed: 0>

Comment: Is the connection string `sqlite:///:memory:` or variations like `sqlite://`?  If not, what is `db` and how is `session` and `read_replica_session` set up and their relation to each other, ideally include the relevant code.

Comment: sorry, updated the post with relevant info

Comment: Please include sufficient code that would form a [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that would reproduce the issue you have encountered - [See example](https://gist.github.com/metatoaster/3199779d612b6deed0046107e9d7ad5e) - I can run the code in the Gist, and that cannot replicate the issue you've seen.